# Sudoers NOPASSWD how to grant access to a specific ln command

Tags: sudo, authorization

In `/etc/sudoers` I need to grant passwordless sudo for this command:

```
/usr/bin/env sudo ln -nfs /home/deployer/apps/myapp_staging/shared/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

to the `deployer` user.

I tried the following without success:

```
deployer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command itself is missing.  Try

```
deployer  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/ln -nfs /home/deployer/apps/myapp_staging/shared/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Comment: I have been trying with `ln -s ...` and the command must be (obviously) with full path `/bin/ln -s ...`. Thx :)